# ServiceStack routing GET requests to POST methods

Tags: c#, servicestack, url-routing

I have been having an issue with Uri too long for a number of GET requests we currently have and our proposed solution is to issue post requests instead.

I'd prefer to keep my service methods using the GetXResponse Get(GetXRequest request) signature.

Is there any way to configure ServiceStack to resolve to Get methods when the request starts with 'Get'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Customize Request Handling with X-Http-Method-Override

There's no special heuristic of Request DTO naming to `Get` actions, but when making the request you can use the `X-Http-Method-Override` in either of the HTTP Header, QueryString or FormData to specify a different verb to execute the request as.

#### Handle any Verb with `Any()` method

You can also use `Any` method to handle **all** verbs (i.e. inc GET/POST), e.g:

```
GetXResponse Any(GetXRequest request) { .. }
```

The `Any` method is used as a fallback, if you also have specific verbs with the same Request DTO it will use those instead, i.e:

```
GetXResponse Get(GetXRequest request) { .. }
GetXResponse Post(GetXRequest request) { .. }
```

Comment: thx wasn't aware of "X-Http-Method-Override" - I've tried to set this via the GlobalRequestFilters on the server side when a request is received and tried various permutations for setting the GET,POST verbs in the Route attribute for the RequestDto but the Get method is never resolved. Seems Any is the only option that is working.

Comment: adding the override to the header before posting the request from the client works perfectly. thanks very much.